# How to use radiobuttons with array?

Tags: java, android, arrays, radio-button

I was interested in making an APP for Android with 30 personality profile questions, where each question will have two alternatives of choice. I thought about using RadioButton, but since there are 30 questions I would not like to include them all on the screen at once, I would like to display only one question with two alternatives and each selection of one of the alternatives already called the other question.

Is it possible to do this without creating 30 activities?

I saw that it might be possible to do array, but I do not know how to run it from one issue to another.

Thank you so much!!!

Comment: Why you duplicated yourself 2 times?

Comment: i dont think so creating 30 activity is good why dont u just show 1 question at a time and change the question after user chooses the right answer this would be more efficent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code achieves the required functionality. It is very basic and can be improved as per your need. Simply add this activity and layout to your project.

**Java File: This code uses a single layout and recreate the view for next question on Radio Button Click**

```
    public class QuestionsActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements 
    RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener{
    LinkedHashMap<String,RadioGroup> questionList;
    LinkedHashMap<String,String> answerList;
    ArrayList<String> keys=new ArrayList<>();
    int keyCounter=0;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_questions);
        questionList=new LinkedHashMap<>(); //This Map contains all the questions with two radio button (options)
        answerList=new LinkedHashMap<>(); //This Map will contain question along with selected answer.

        initQuestions(); //This method will add 30 questions with options

        keys.addAll(questionList.keySet());

        showQuestions(keys.get(keyCounter));//This method will show the first question






    }

    private void showQuestions(String key) {
        TextView textView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_question);
        textView.setText(key);
        LinearLayout layout =(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.questionsLayout);
        layout.removeAllViews();
        RadioGroup rg=questionList.get(key);
        rg.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        layout.addView(rg);
        rg.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);


    }

    private void initQuestions() {
        for (int i = 1; i <=3; i++) {
            RadioGroup rg=new RadioGroup(this);
            RadioButton rb1 =new RadioButton(this);
            rb1.setText("Q "+i+" RadioButton 1");
            RadioButton rb2 =new RadioButton(this);
            rb2.setText("Q "+i+" RadioButton 2");
            rg.addView(rb1);rg.addView(rb2);
            questionList.put("Question "+i,rg);


        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, @IdRes int checkedId) {
        RadioButton rb=(RadioButton) findViewById(group.getCheckedRadioButtonId());




        if(keyCounter<questionList.size()) {
            answerList.put(keys.get(keyCounter),rb.getText().toString());  // Putting the question and selected answer to 'answerList' map.
            keyCounter++;
            if(keyCounter<questionList.size()) {
                showQuestions(keys.get(keyCounter));// showing the next question.
            }

        }else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "You've answered all the questions.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        for (String s : answerList.keySet()) {
            System.out.println("Q--> "+s+", A--> "+answerList.get(s)); // Here you can see all the questions and selected answers on your logs(AndroidMonitor).
        }
    }
    }
```

**layout file : This file contains a textView which will be used to show question and a linear layout which contains the RadioGroup**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="edios.endlessscrollrecycler.QuestionsActivity">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_question"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:id="@+id/questionsLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"></LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```